# Correctly using rlang::as_function formula within .predicate argument of mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I would like to use `~ . %% 1 == 0` formula within `.predicate` argument of `mutate_if` in the following manner:

```
dta %>%
    mutate_if(.predicate =  ~ . %% 1 == 0,
              .funs = funs(. + 10))
```

where `dta` corresponds to the following tibble:

```
dta <- tibble(colA = c("a", "b"),
              colB = 1:2,
              colC = c(1.1, 2.2))
```

This currently produces the following error:

> Error in `.%%1` : non-numeric argument to binary operator

## Background

In the documentation of [`dplyr::mutate_if`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) states:

> **.predicate**     A predicate function to be applied to the columns or a
>   logical vector. The variables for which .predicate is or returns TRUE
>   are selected. This argument is passed to [`rlang::as_function()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html) and thus
>   supports quosure-style lambda functions and strings representing
>   function names.

Conseqnuetly the formula `~ . %% 1 == 0` can be used in the following manner:

```
f_rlang_check <- rlang::as_function( ~ . %% 1 == 0)

f_rlang_check(c(1.1, 1))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Clearly the formula is correct; however it cannot be directly passed to the [`rlang::as_function()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html) as shown above.

```
dta %>%
    mutate_if(.predicate = f_rlang_check,
              .funs = funs(. + 10))
```

*Produces identical error*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mutate_if` will atempt to evaluate the predicate function for all columns, so you get an error when attempting to use the binary operator `%%` with a non-numeric argument `colA`. You can fix this with `is.numeric` and `&&`.

The predicate should return a single logical value, so you may want to use `all` or `any`.

```
dta %>%
    mutate_if(.predicate = ~ is.numeric(.) && all(. %% 1 == 0),
              .funs = funs(. + 10))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, now I see what was the issue. Why you decided to use `&&` insetad of `&`, if there a risk of wrong results by focusing on comaparing first values only or it always compares one-by-one when using `.predicate`?

Comment: If you use `&` then both sides of `&` will be evaluated, which produces an error in this case. With `&&`, the RHS is only evalued if the LHS is `TRUE` (If it's `FALSE`, the total result is `FALSE` anyway so it doesn't need to check the RHS) This is stated in what may be a non-obvious way by the documentation as " Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined."

Comment: Excellent, Thanks very much.